# Suppress return types in sbt console / Scala REPL

Tags: scala, sbt, read-eval-print-loop

I remember there is switch somewhere to suppress the printing of return types in the Scala REPL, but I cannot find it. I am particularly interested in adding this switch to an sbt build file. Something like `returnTypes in console := false`.

E.g. now I have

```
scala> within( Span( 0, 33 ))
res7: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[(de.sciss.lucre.expr.SpanLike, scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[(de.sciss.lucre.expr.Expr[de.sciss.lucre.stm.InMemory,de.sciss.lucre.expr.SpanLike], de.sciss.lucre.expr.Expr[de.sciss.lucre.stm.InMemory,Long])])] = Vector()
```

and for obvious reasons I want

```
scala> within( Span( 0, 33 ))
res7: Vector()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My question is basically mirrored by [this mailing-list question](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/11813). Based on Rex Kerr's idea, the following could go into `build.sbt`:

```
initialCommands in console := """// helper method to disable type printing
def shortresults[T](t: => T) = {
   val s = t.toString
   val name = s.takeWhile(_ != ':')
   val idx = s.indexOf(" = ")
   val full = if (idx >= 0) name + s.substring(idx) else s
   val short = if (full.length>799) full.substring(0,796)+"..." else full
   print(short)
   t
}
"""
```

But unfortunately, still the following three REPL escape commands need to be manually executed after the console is up and running:

```
:power
:wrap shortresults
:silent
```